# WPF: Databinding with ComboBox

Tags: wpf, binding

The below code works for a DataGridComboBoxColumn, but ComboBox doesn't have a SelectedValueBinding property. What should I use instead?

```
<ComboBox
    Header="Application"  
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ApplicationKey}" 
    SelectedValuePath="ApplicationKey"  
    DisplayMemberPath="ApplicationName"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static app:ApplicationLookup.GetAllOrNone}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
`SelectedValue = {Binding Property}`
or `SelectedItem = {Binding Property}`

these will have the same effect
and to get the Path that you want to display use
`DisplayMemberPath = Property`

Comment: Now why couldn't the datagrid be that easy? Oh well, thanks for your help.